# Expo: Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation')]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have been working on React Native and I am getting this error any help will be appreciable!

**My App.js Screen**

```js
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AppNavigator from "./navigation/AppNavigator";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**My HomeScreen.js Screen**

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, Image,View,Text } from 'react-native';
import { Button, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
// <View style={styles.container}>
const HomeScreen=(props)=> {
    const logout =(props)=>{
        AsyncStorage.removeItem("token").then(()=>{
          props.navigation.replace("login")
        })
     }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> Your Email is XYZ </Text>
        <Button
          style={styles.btnStyle}
          mode="contained"
          onPress={() => logout()}
        >
          LOG OUT
        </Button>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        fontSize:18,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    btnStyle: {
        marginLeft: 18,
        marginRight: 18,
        marginTop: 30,
        backgroundColor: "black",
        textShadowColor: "white",
        borderRadius: 35,
    },
  
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

**My AppNavigator.js**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import SignUp from "../screens/SignupScreen";
import LoginScreen from "../screens/LoginScreen";
import LoadingScreen from "../screens/LoadingScreen";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function AppNavigator() {
  const [isLoggedin, setLogged] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token) {
      setLogged(true)
    }
    else {
      setLogged(false)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      headerMode="none"
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: { elevation: 0 },
        cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' }
      }}
    >


      <Stack.Screen name="loading" component={LoadingScreen}></Stack.Screen>
      <Stack.Screen name="home" component={HomeScreen}></Stack.Screen>

      <Stack.Screen name="login" component={LoginScreen}></Stack.Screen>
      <Stack.Screen name="signup" component={SignUp}></Stack.Screen>


    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default AppNavigator;
```

**The error I am getting is**

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation')]
at screens\HomeScreen.js:9:8 in logout
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `HomeScreen.js` change your Logout function to this -

```
  const logout = () => { // You were passing a props variable here that was undefined..
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('token').then(() => {
      props.navigation.replace('login');
    });
  };
```

Check out [this](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/navigation-flow) Snack that I created... Just to show you the implementation

I would also suggest you to not restore token in your `AppNavigator.js`. Instead you should install `expo-app-loading` and restore your token inside your `App.js`

And also, its not a good practice to perform `async` operations inside a `useEffect`.. Check out the `Snack` link above for how you should implement it.. I've created a somewhat clone of it..Have a look

Answer (score 0):

Your Stack.screens are not wrapped with NavigationContainer and navigation props is not passed down to your screens/components.

Please check https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation

```
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
          headerMode="none"
          screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: { elevation: 0 },
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' }
     }}>
       <Stack.Screen name="signup" component={SignUp}></Stack.Screen>
       .....
     </Stack.Navigator>
   <NavigationContainer>
 );
```

Comment: Yeah I am doing that in my App.js, I am updating the above question with my App.js file too

Comment: can you pease log what props are passed to HomeScreen component.

Comment: I get undefined when I log props.

Comment: Yes thats because you are not using the `props` that is defined at the top...Check my answer